# what is the different between string and stringbuilder in the code?

Tags: java

i would like to know why the output of this code is "roar roar!!!" not "roar!!! roar!!!"?
the code is:

```
 public class Lion 
 {
   public void roar(String roar1, StringBuilder roar2) {
   roar1.concat("!!!");
   roar2.append("!!!");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String roar1 = "roar";
  StringBuilder roar2 = new StringBuilder("roar");
  new Lion().roar(roar1, roar2);
  System.out.println(roar1 + " " + roar2);
} }
```

i try to find the reason of method concat() dont appends one String to the end of another. please with explain.

Comment: A String is immutable see the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Here roar1 is you string variable and roar2 is your object of class string builder, and only string builder is mutable, string can not be mutated.... Because of which only inbuilt function in class string builder concate will work on its object roar2.

Roar1 is not object of string builder thus concate function will not work on it.

Comment: `String` provide method to create new instance, instead of modifying the instance itself, because it is immutable. So your last sentence is incorrect. And for the rest, I had problem to understand half of the answer. Please use some tags and try to correct yourself if you can

Comment: I was saying that, since roar1 is variable not the object of string builder class and concate function will work only for  string builder object not for primitive data type.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, Objects of the class String are always immutable.
Additionally you have to remember how variables in JAVA are passed to some Methods.
In your case you build a String and a StringBuilder an pass them to your roar() method. The JVM will create two new Variables which are referencing the two orignal Objects. Due to the immutablity of your local String Variable, a new Object will be created, if you want to change this Object. The append() method of an String Object, normally creates and returns a new Instance of a String, with the changes you've made. You doesn't have a reference on this Object. Even if your local String references this object, the String Variable outside of the roar() method still references the old String ("roar"). 
That's the reason why your System.out.println, doesn't show the changes you made.

Comment: `Your Local Variable is referencing this new String ("roar!!!")` this is incorrect. Read the code again ;) but even if this was correctly written, you are not wrong either.